# Chad Gadya Protects Us From Jealous Angels?

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, malach-angel

Someone told me in the name of Rav Ephraim Wachsman that after the angels see how much pleasure our Pesach Sedarim give Hashem, they become jealous, which creates an element of danger for Klal Yisroel. Consequently, Chad Gadya is said to protect us from the potential negative effects of the jealousy.

What is the source for this concept? (Preferably, how does that work?)

Comment: That sounds pretty crazy (a bit Christian).

Comment: I don't know, @pcoz, there are those who say this is the reason we say Kaddish in Aramaic as well

Answer (score 0):

I just saw the Abudraham on the Haggadah says this is why we say *Ha Lachma Anya* in Aramaic, so the Angels won't understand what we're saying (since Angels don't understand Aramaic). If they understood, they would get mad at us that we're boasting about becoming free, and remind Hashem of our sins. It sounds like he was saying this on all the Aramaic parts of the Haggadah.

This could apply to *Chad Gadya*, which is also in Aramaic. He's not exactly saying that the song protects us, but perhaps Rav Wachsman meant like the Abudraham, that it's in Aramaic to avoid this danger.

Comment: "_He's not exactly saying that the song protects us_ ..." He would have been hard pressed to do so, as (based on Wikipedia's "[David Abudarham](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Abudarham)" and "[Chad Gadya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chad_Gadya)") he lived (around 1340) a good 200 or so years before the first known publication of Chad Gadya (in the Prague Haggadah of 1590).